# angularjs expression not evaluating for bootstrap data-target

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm required to populate my bootstrap powered left navigation based on permissions stored in database. 
Permission based menu data set will be fed from web api 
So i tried to extend http://jsfiddle.net/kmussel/evXFZ/ directives to change my static menu to dynamic menu .

Everything goes well except collapse functionality is not working as expressions for dynamic ids for data-target is not evaluated somehow.

I have created http://jsfiddle.net/jaimini/gKnJ2/1/ ti mimic the issue I'm facing.

```
data-target="{{node.id}}"
```

is not evaluated and hence expand/collapse is not working.
I have also added hardcoded IDs in 2nd menu to show that my approach will work if the expression is evaluated as required.

Comment: I do not understand why must write a directive for menu. fancier? I create menu in the html and menu interact with a controller.

Comment: I think you missed the dynamic part based on permission. may be you can explain your approach little bit more so that I might get some hints to rethink my approach.I need to hide/show menus based on user permission how you gonna achieve that requirement. with ng-if?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to solve the issue by removing target attribute from parent link.
updated the fiddle and now its working as per my need.

please note that for proper functioning of bootstrap collapse plugin

```
data-target="{{\'#navigation\'+node.id}}"
```

would be required.

Answer (score 0):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zzal/qdvuN/10/) is like yours, it use recursive `ng-repeat`. The googgle discussion about rendering tree like structure is [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/TbpjE-5XEM0).

The different between `ng-if` `ng-switch` to `ng-show` `ng-hide` is, `ng-if` will not render the html
if the condition not met rather than render those elements that is hidden but taking up
resources. It is not evident for menus because there are not alot of binding/watches use. But
imagine you have render 5 - 6 tabs with lots of form data.